# meaning of $C_4$ tree in graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was reading a paper. There a term was defined as $C_4$ tree. It was written that a graph is $C_n$ tree if it can b constructed from $C_n$ by a finite number of applications of the following theorem : add a new $C_n$ and identify an edge of this graph with an edge of existing graph. Can anybody explain me what it means? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hmm I don't think that I have enough context but $C_n$ usually means a cycle of length $n$, and maybe you have a tree and adding an edge causes you to create a $C_n$.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre yeah $C_n$ is cycle graph :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let’s make sure that you understand the operation. I start with the copy of $C_4$ at the left in the picture below. I then add to it a second copy of $C_4$, shown immediately to its right, by identifying the edge $e$ of the first copy with the edge $e'$ of the second copy; the result is the graph shown at $(2)$. If I perform the operation again by adding a third copy of $C_4$, this time identifying its top edge with the lower right edge of $(2)$, I get $(3)$.

```
       *---*     *---*      *---*---*        *---*---*   
       |   |e  e'|   |      |  e|e' |        |   |   |   
       *---*     *---*      *---*---*        *---*---*  
                                                 |   |  
                                                 *---*  
             (1)               (2)              (3)
```

Suppose that I replace each copy of $C_4$ by a vertex and join two vertices by an edge if the corresponding copies of $C_4$ have been sewn together by this operation. My original $C_4$, the graph in $(2)$ and the graph in $(3)$ turn into these trees:

```
              *               *---*            *---*  
                                                   |  
                                                   *
```

More generally, suppose that $G$ is a $C_n$ tree graph. That means that $G$ is constructed from a copy of $C_n$ in some finite number $m$ of steps, each of which is an application of the attaching operation. We can describe it this way. For $k=0,1,\ldots,m$ let $A_k$ be a copy of $C_n$. I start with $G_0=A_0$. Then I form $G_1$ by adding $A_1$, the second $C_n$, graph, identifying one of its edges with one edge of $G_0$. Then I form $G_2$ by adding $A_2$, identifying one of its edges with one edge of $G_1$. I continue in this fashion until I’ve formed $G_m=G$ by adding $A_m$ to $G_{m-1}$. Note that at stage $k$ the $C_n$ copy $A_k$ is attached along an edge to exactly one $A_j$ with $j<k$.

Now let $V=\{v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ be a set of $m+1$ vertices; the idea is that $v_k$ is to correspond to $A_k$ for $k=0,\ldots,m$. $V$ is to be the vertex set of a new graph $T$; if $1\le j<k\le m$, $\{v_j,v_k\}$ is an edge of $T$ iff $A_k$ was attached along an edge of $A_j$ when it was added at stage $k$ to produce $G_k$. If $n=4$ and $m=2$, for instance, the graphs in the top picture are $G_0,G_1$, and $G_2$, and the graph at the right in the lower picture is $T$.

You can think of $T$ as being a sort of skeleton of $G$, and the reason for the name $C_n$ *tree graph* is that this skeleton $T$ is always a tree. (This isn’t too hard to prove.)

Comment: thank you very much for the nice explanation. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @monalisa: You’re very welcome.